# spark dataframe column string to date

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, str-to-date

I would like to convert a spark dataframe string column of 'yyyyMMdd' to date format with spark session (spark) - not spark context.

Since I'm not working with spark context (sc), I cannot use the following code, although it would precisly do what I'd like it to do:

```
.withColumn("column1",DF.to_date(F.col("column1"),"yyyyMMdd"))
```

As I do not want to convert the column to timestamp, I also don't want to use the following code:

```
.withColumn("column1", unix_timestamp(col("column1"), "yyyyMMdd").cast("timestamp"))
```

The final goal is to replace the former string column by the date formatted column.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you use the first option, did you try running it ?

Answer (score 1):

the following code works fine:

```
.withColumn("column1", to_date(DF["column1"], 'yyyyMMdd'))
```

Thanks for your attention!